# How to use webrtc-adapter npm package in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, next.js

I am creating a React with Next.js. My ES6 imports work just fine for the .js files I create, but when I import `webrtc-adapter` it fails in next, but succeeds in react-app:

```
import {adapterFactory} from './adapter_factory.js';
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

For example here are the two links which repro:

- FAILS (Next): https://repl.it/repls/SafeWorseEngine
- WORKS (CRA): https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cjxz7s?file=index.js

The following is the reduced test case. Just import `webrtc-adapter` and console it out. Works in CRA but not in Next.

Importing ES6 in my own files work great, but not foreign packages. Any ideas?

```
{
  "name": "webrtc-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.0-alpha.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0-alpha.0",
    "webrtc-adapter": "^7.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
}
```

In pages/index.js

```
import adapter from 'webrtc-adapter';
console.log(adapter);
export default () => <div>Welcome to next!</div>;
```

I even tried:

```
import 'webrtc-adapter';
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you try to run/build it in your local environment? Seems the issue might not be related to the library but caused by the node version not supporting `import` or `export`

Comment: @Van I am running node v11.6.0 Even the online next.js repls failing as well. I believe it is that the library webrtc-adapter does not use commonjs?

Comment: what if you try to import it as so `import * as adapter from 'webrtc-adapter'`

Comment: @Van same error https://repl.it/repls/TroubledSuperiorTutorial

Comment: Something to do with SSR, where when it transpiles it, nextjs gets confused

Comment: hmm really strange, I tried to run it in my local environment and got the same issue that you encountered. Seems nextjs got some issue when transpiling, any specific reason why you have to use nextjs and not cra?

Comment: I also tried to change the `main` and `module` entry point for `webrtc-adapter` module in node_modules to target the `./dist/...` folder (the transpiled files to es5) instead, but the module will break. If using nextjs is a requirement, you could probably try to fork webrtc-adapter module, transpile it, and publish the fork to use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since Next.JS compiles on the server and the client, you can't be sure you are in a browser context (window is undefined).

To fix this often you can use a simple check like:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  var adapter = require('webrtc-adapter')
}
```

to ensure you're within a browser context